# AWS static site endpoint not loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to point a domain to an S3 bucket set up for static website hosting. I changed the original DNS nameservers to use AWS nameservers instead and set up the following DNS records:

[image]

There is an alias A record for the domain itself as well as one for www.

When I try to go to the domain, it takes me to the company's site where the nameservers are managed (domainspricedright.com) and it says it's a parked site, or it just loads forever then fails.

When I try to go to the endpoint URL itself, it fails to ever load, which maybe means there is some permissions issue with the bucket? The endpoint is:
http://sunrisevalleydds.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

The bucket policy I have in place is:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sunrisevalleydds.com/*"
    }
]
```

}

Perhaps it's a propagation delay? I don't know really how to debug it.

Edit: The endpoint loads now. But http://sunrisevalleydds.com and http://www.sunrisevalleydds.com fail to load. Still not sure if this is a delay.

Comment: both the url loads for me

Comment: Seems to have been a delay. They are now loading for me. Will close this question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been a propagation delay. URLs are now loading.